# Memory management when working with pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I have these scenarios and I want to know if I manage my memory correctly. I watch the memory consumption in the Task Manager when I start the executable and see how memory is not popped back to the initial amount, which leads me to suspect that I don't clear memory where is needed.
So, in this first case I have a function that adds a new element to a dynamic array:

```
struct Color {
    int R;
    int G;
    int B;
}

int TotalColors;
Color* Rainbow;

void AddColor(Color NewColor) {
    // So, I create a new array of size TotalColors+1
    Color* NewRainbow = new Color[TotalColors+1];
    // Now I add the existing elements
    for (int i=0; i<TotalColors; i++) {
        NewRainbow[i] = Rainbow[i];
    }
    // And lastly, I add the new element
    NewRainbow[TotalColors] = NewColor;
    // Now, I assign the NewRainbow to Rainbow (I don't know if it's correct)
    Rainbow = NewRainbow;
}
```

So, in this case, do you think I miss something? This is working but I want to make sure the unused stuff is removed from memory.
I also have a function to remove an element, which looks like this:

```
void RemoveColor(Color Removable) {
    // Again, I create a new array of size TotalColors-1
    Color* NewRainbow = new Color[TotalColors-1];
    // I scan the list and add only those elements which are not 'Removable'
    for (int i=0; i<TotalColors; i++) {
        // Let's suppose that Removable exists in the list
        if (Rainbow[i].R != Removable.R && Raibow[i].G != Removable.G && ... {
            NewRainbow [i] = Rainbow[i];
        }
    }
    // Again, the same operation as above
    NewRainbow[TotalColors] = NewColor;
    Rainbow = NewRainbow;
}
```

In this case, I don't know what happens with Rainbow[Removable], I mean, the element of the array that is removed.
And the last case, is this, where I try to send the pointer of an element from the array to a function.

```
Color* GetColor(int Index) {
    Color* FoundColor;
    // Scan the array
    for (int i=0; i<TotalColors; i++) {
        if (i == Index) FoundColor = &Rainbow[i];
    }
    return FoundColor;
}

// And I use it like this
void ChangeColor(int Index) {
    Color* Changeable;
    Changeable = GetColor(Index);
    SetRGB(Changeable, 100, 100, 100);
}

// And this is what changes the value
void SetRGB(Color* OldRGB, int R, int G, int B) {
    (*oldRGB).R = R;
    (*oldRGB).G = G;
    (*oldRGB).B = B;
}
```

And this is it. So, this works but I am not sure if with so many pointers I didn't forget to delete something. For example, when I `RemoveColor` I don't see the memory changed (maybe some bytes don't make the difference) and I just want some professional eye to tell me if I missed something. Thanks!

Comment: Managing raw pointers can indeed be tricky.  Is there a reason not to use smart pointers?

Comment: Just learning. I can use vectors, too. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first function `AddColor()` you are not deleting the previously allocated memory.

```
Rainbow = NewRainbow; // leaking the memory Rainbow was previously pointing to.
```

Change that last line to:

```
delete[] Rainbow;
Rainbow = NewRainbow;
```

Same thing with `RemoveColor()`

Any time you use the `new` operator it needs to have a corresponding `delete`. Also, if you are allocating an array with `new[]` as in your case, it must have a corresponding `delete[]`.

Comment: Of course better than manually pairing up `new`/`delete`, `new[]`/`delete[]`, etc. is to use RAII.

Answer (score 1):

In order not to worry whether you've forgotten to delete a pointer, you shouldn't use plain pointers. Instead, use smart pointers such as

```
std::shared_ptr
std::unique_ptr
etc.
```

or, if you don't have C++11 yet, use

```
boost::shared_ptr
boost::scoped_ptr
```

More on smart pointers, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_smart_pointers) and the specific documentation.

Comment: Please get a good understanding of C++ memory management using `new` and `delete` before moving on to smart pointers. They are powerful and do save you some headaches but also introduce their own problems that can be difficult to track down if you don't fully understand C++ memory management in general.